# Issue with layout inside scroll view

Tags: android, android-layout

I have this layout:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/username_edittext"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="@string/username"
            android:textColor="@color/dark_grey" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/password_edittext"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/username_edittext"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="@string/password"
            android:textColor="@color/dark_grey" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/login_button"
            style="@style/ButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/password_edittext"
            android:text="@string/login" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

and it is shown as:

[image]

But I want align the button "Entrar" (login_button) at bottom of the screen. RelativeLayout is not filling parent (ScrollView) so `alignParentBottom = true` in the button is not working properly.

What can I do?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need to have the parent view be a ScrollView? If you set the RelativeLayout to match_parent it will always be the same size as the ScrollView and nothing will ever scroll. 

Is there any content that you want to scroll in this view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved! I have added `android:fillViewport="true"` in the ScrollView and removed the `android:layout_below="@id/password_edittext"` from the Button.

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/username_edittext"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="@string/username"
            android:textColor="@color/dark_grey" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/password_edittext"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/username_edittext"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="@string/password"
            android:textColor="@color/dark_grey" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/login_button"
            style="@style/ButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:text="@string/login" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

[image]